# \E can't replace from= '\E\\E\10.1.2.154\E\bcs\E\30877_P9999_Adult{2}_02_05_2019_0329p.pdf'

Tags: javascript, regex

```
var str='\E\\E\10.1.2.154\E\bcs\E\30877_P9999_Adult{2}_02_05_2019_0329p.pdf';
var res=str.replace('\E', '');
```

I am getting return like this:

```
\E.1.2.154EcsE877_P9999_Adult{2}_02_05_2019_0329p.pdf
```

I need to replace all `'\E'` from string  and expecting output like this `(\\10.1.2.154\bcs\30877_P9999_Adult{2}_02_05_2019_0329p.pdf)`. Some body please advise on this . I tried to do several way to fix this. No luck. When I tried with C# it's working fine.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string str=@"\E\\E\10.1.2.154\E\bcs\E\30877_P9999_Adult{2}_02_05_2019_0329p.pdf";
    str=str.Replace(@"\E","");
    Console.WriteLine(str);
    Console.Read();
}
```

But, I need it in JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var str='\E\\E\10.1.2.154\E\bcs\E\30877_P9999_Adult{2}_02_05_2019_0329p.pdf';
var res=str.replace(/\\E/g, '');
console.log(str, res)
```

You must use RegExg to eliminate the escape inside a string in JavaScript.

Comment: It doesn't return the output as below even if i use RegExg :  
 \\10.1.2.154\bcs\30877_P9999_Adult{2}_02_05_2019_0329p.pdf

Comment: what do you want as output?

Comment: \\10.1.2.154\bcs\30877_P9999_Adult{2}_02_05_2019_0329p.pdf

Answer (score 0):

In JavaScript the equivalent of the C# `@` prefix is [`String.raw`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/raw) followed by a template literal (notice the backtics).

And to replace all occurrences, not just one, you need to pass a regex to `replace` with `g` modifier.

```js
var str=String.raw`\E\\E\10.1.2.154\E\bcs\E\30877_P9999_Adult{2}_02_05_2019_0329p.pdf`;
var res=str.replace(/\\E/g, '');

console.log(res);
```

NB: The backslash in a regular expression is an escape character, so you need `\\` for one literal backslash.

If for some reason you really want to avoid the use of a regex, then there is the `split/join` trick, but it is a bit slower:

```js
var str=String.raw`\E\\E\10.1.2.154\E\bcs\E\30877_P9999_Adult{2}_02_05_2019_0329p.pdf`;
var res=str.split(String.raw`\E`).join('');

console.log(res);
```

#### Older JS engines

For older JS engines that do not support `String.raw` you need to use standard string literals, which use the backslash as escape character. So then you need to double all of them. But this is only needed when you write the string as a literal. When you get the string via some API, then there is no need to alter the string before doing the replacement:

```js
var str='\\E\\\\E\\10.1.2.154\\E\\bcs\\E\\30877_P9999_Adult{2}_02_05_2019_0329p.pdf';
var res=str.replace(/\\E/g, '');

console.log(res);
```

Comment: Thank you so much . That make sense :)

Comment: This perfectly works in standard  java script  . Do you think any other alternative solution  on it . I am writing java script in mirth connect .  Those compiler  doesn't identified   String.raw.  Thanks

Comment: In that case you need to write your string literals taking into account that backslash is an escape character. See addition to my answer.

Comment: thanks for your prompt response .Above logic will work fine . I am getting data as HL7 standard . its a result of some investigation (Shared path).  Again difficult to add \ beginning of each  \ character .  any short code  to add extra \ of all \ . Please advise . then we can apply above logic .

Comment: If you get the strings from some data source (database, HTTP request, ...) then there is no need to add extra backslashes. The extra backslash is only needed in string *literals*. But as you get the data from some source, you will actually not have such literals in your code. So I am not sure what problem you are still facing?

Comment: Just to be sure we understand eachother: `'\\'` is a string with one character, a backslash. If you get a string with one backslash from some other source and have it stored in variable `s`, then the following is true: `s === '\\'`.